# Drop ssh connection if file exists

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-access, ssh-keys

In order to be allowed to use ssh-key logins, I have been asked to make sure that any new connections will fail when the server is in maintenance mode. I can identify if the server is in maintenance mode by checking if a file exists. What I have tried so far is putting the following in my .ssh/rc file, but I am still able to connect. Anyone have a better solution?

```
if [ -e $CHECK_FILE ]
then
    echo "Under Maintenance... login disabled"
    kill -9 $$
    #exit -1
fi
```

Comment: Just use [`/etc/nologin`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd%288%29#FILES)?

Comment: Make sure you can login direct as root before doing this: `echo "Under Maintenance... login disabled" > /etc/nologin`

Comment: doesn't `exit` work?

Comment: @shellter: sshd runs something like this: `sh -c "/bin/bash -c '/bin/sh .ssh/rc'"` and you leave only sh script rc.

Comment: @cyrus : Thanks, Good to know. :-)

Comment: That is probably typically what you would do... but I am not the server maintainer just a user.

Comment: Why not just shutdown sshd if $CHECK_FILE exists and start sshd if $CHECK_FILE doesn't exists?  Oh yeah.  Make sure you have console access.

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would want to do this. What's the purpose? Once someone has access to the server, they can start background processes, crontabs, etc. Why not just firewall the SSH port from all the networks except the one(s) you need to manage the machine from?

Comment: I agree that it doesn't make sense, but I want to be able to use the super-computer and the maintainer has given me this arbitrary request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Linux kill your own sshd from `~/.ssh/rc`:

```
killall sshd
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have thought of that. It does just what I was looking for. I do note though that chepner is right about this not being the appropriate way to handle things... but I am not in charge of the server nor it's maintenance. But in order to use the server I have to live with the managers arbitrary requests.

Answer (score 1):

Create `/etc/nologin` with a maintenance message to prevent any logins via `ssh` (or just kill `sshd` for the duration).

However, if maintenance is done *via* `ssh`, then you need to allow *some* user to log in. In that case, update `/etc/sshd_config` with something like

```
AllowUsers bob
```

to prevent anyone except "bob" from logging in.

Comment: I will suggest this to the server maintainer, but I am just a user. Do you know of a way for me to automatically kill my own connection?

Comment: *Anything* you put on the remote host implies that you can connect before that executes. This is *really* not something you, as the user, should be responsible for. If the administrators don't want people logging in during maintenance, they should make the system unavailable rather than relying on users to log out immediately.